# Efficient way to Report automated data-driven tests (csv) on vs-team-services

Tags: c#, automated-tests, azure-devops, reporting, data-driven-tests

I have been searching for about 2 weeks but sadly couldn't find any efficient solution.

The UseCase isnt very tricky. I will try to discribe shortly:

**The Situation:**

I implemented automated C# Web-Service tests using *Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting* . 
These tests are running nightly via a Build-Job on vs-team-services . 
Reporting is nice and traceable (epic/feature/task --> testcase --> bug) as long as i don't use data-driven tests. (I used test-suites and testcase-workitems and configured "associated automation" of eacht testcase)

**The Problem is:**
If i use data-driven tests (csv-files) i can...

1) ...annotate the testmethods in the code with the Testcategory attribute and configure a test-assembly in the build, which will then run all testmethods with the assigned / configured Testcategory. In this case the testrun or build contains a report for every single data-row, which is fine. But the traceability is totally lost, because there are no testcases (vsts-workitems) that could be related to a task or bug.

2) ...create a testcase (workitem), add it to a test-suite/-plan and configure the build to run the suite / plan. Now the traceability is "fine", because the testcase can be related to a task or bug. But the report of the build contains only one single testcase, even the csv-file has e.g. 200 data-rows. Where each data-row contains data for one single test. So e.g, if one data-row (test) fails, the testcase (vsts-workitem) has failed, even if 199 tests succeeded.

**What i am looking for:**

The first approach with the possibility for traceability or the second approach with a reporting for each data-row.

I am wondering that this topic hasn't been discussed before and looking forward to new opportunities / approaches. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about the custom build result extension with detail test result? (read detail test result from result file, e.g. trx)

Comment: I have checked the trx file which is attached to the Test-**RUN** and it shows me a different result as the **BUILD** do. You are right all of the DD-Tests are shown with its results. 
So i have to point out that the **BUILD** result differs from the Test-**RUN** result. I couldn't find any good reason, why this should have been designed that way.
(This is the behaviour if you use TestCase Workitems and associate the automation with it.)

Comment: Regarding driven test, it is just a test point even though there are many data rows. So, if there is the record failed, then the final result is fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can add traceability from an automated test result directly to a Backlog Item. You can then see the requirements associated in the build, and create a Requirements Quality dashboard widget...

If you open a Build and go to the test results you can select an individual result, and then add a related work item. In all future builds the data will be related.

Then go to your dashboard and add the Requirement la Quality widget and configure it for that build.